# Could not find the file and upload

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I trying to do multiple image upload to the system but it won't able to found the images after upload. 
When i try to var_dump the total number of item uploaded it keep showing 0 item uploaded.

Need some help here, Thank You.

This is my HTML code:

```
<form id="login-form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple"  />
<input type="submit" name="submit-scam" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
//Check Error
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//Start Session
session_start();
//Include Database
include_once('dbConnect.php');


if (isset($_POST['submit-scam'])){
    echo "button clicked";

if(isset($_FILES['file'])){ 

            /*This Function is to loop multiple upload file into DB*/

    $total = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

    for ($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {

    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
    $folder="uploads/";
    $today = date('Y-m-d');

    // new file size in KB
    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    // new file size in KB

    // make file name in lower case
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    // make file name in lower case

    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);


    if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
    {

                    //To Insert Latest base to SQL Latest submit ec_claim id 

                    $sql="INSERT INTO db_evidence(db_evidence_name,db_evidence_type,db_evidence_scam_id,db_evidence_users_id) 
                    VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','1','1')";
                    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
                    echo "success upload";
                    // header("Location:index.php");
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "failed to upload";
                }
                }
            } else {
                echo "error no file is found";
            }
}
?>
```

Comment: replace `isset($_FILES['file']` this with `isset($_FILES['file']['name']` or `!empty($_FILES['file']['name']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`enctype="multipart/form-data"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) to the form

```
<form id="login-form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple"  />
    <input type="submit" name="submit-scam" value="Submit">
</form>
```

That should let you read from `type="file"`

Comment: Thanks for reply, i tried to add "enctype" just now, it still can't get the image...

Comment: No error message was show, but i use my own isset filter it shows "file" is empty

Comment: Somehow it working now! Thanks for helping! Up-vote for you